# vendor:publish not publishing the javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vendor, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to publish this:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/1.3.0-rc.6

inside my assets folder (public)

I used to be able to do:

```
php artisan asset:publish name/of/package
```

but now I see there is a new command

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

but how do I tell it which packages to publish?

I I just run the above function, it says `publishing complete!` but nothing has been moved, obviously.

Any ideas?

---

I have tried:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="vendor\eternicode\bootstrap-datepicker" .
```

which throws "too many arguments"

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="vendor\eternicode\bootstrap-datepicker"
```

which says successful but hasn't actually published anything to my public folder

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker"
```

which says successful but hasn't actually published anything to my public folder

Comment: maybe you can see the answer in this question. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090564/vendorpublish-nothing-to-publish-for-tag-only-on-production-server)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add/change your package's [`ServiceProvider`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#service-providers).

Add something like this:

```
<?php namespace your_namespace;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class YourServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    // [...]

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // [...]

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/assets' => public_path('vendor/your_package'),
        ], 'public');
    }

    // [...]
}
```

And don't forget to register you `ServiceProvider` in `config/app.php`.

The new `Laravel 5` command is just

```
php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with something like this:

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor\twbs\bootstrap-sass\assets"  .
```

It's only example how I published Bootstrap Sass assets.

Notice the dot at the end of command - it's necessary - without it it doesn't work as it should.

---

**Edited Date:- 2nd April, 2022**

Unfortunately `php artisan asset:publish` does not exist in Laravel 5 & above versions.

for Laravel 5+ you need to use `php artisan vendor:publish`. [refer Official Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#public-assets)

Comment: Unfortuantely asset:publish does not exist in Laravel 5. It looks like it was replaced by vendor:publish (shrugs)... and this does not support the --path option. There is a "provider" option... I've added to OP