# Vendor:Publish - Nothing to publish for tag [] - Only on production server

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am using a third party library and locally, I installed everything using the **steps** that they provided.

1. I ran `composer require` on the package and ran an update. This installed into the `vendor` folder.
2. I then added the path into the `provider` in `config/app` and also as an aliases..
3. I ran `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsServiceProvider"` the config file created successfully and I had no problems.
4. I then uploaded to the production environment and kept on getting `Class 'LaravelAnalytics' not found` and I can't seem to figure out the problem..
5. I ran `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsServiceProvider"`

But I kept on getting: `Nothing to publish for tag [].` which has lead me to thinking that this could be the problem since the package is not published.

My local environment is Ubuntu and my production Environment is CentOS.. If I try to CD into that directory on my production environment it says cannot find.

Could this therefore be a problem with the case sensitive on how I am adding my providers that is not picking up this package?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

are you using cached config files ?
try using

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and retry

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Comment: @frvanhover - I forgot to post an answer to this, but this was kind of the solution however I had to delete all of the config cache in order to run the other commands

Answer (score -1):

You have to save all for the project before (php artisan vendor:publish).