# can't publish cloudconvert API in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cloudconvert

I want to use cloudconvert API in laravel but when I run

`php artisan vendor:publish`

no cloudconvert.php file is created in config folder.

I am following this link https://github.com/robbiepaul/cloudconvert-laravel

Please help

Comment: I followed below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090564/vendorpublish-nothing-to-publish-for-tag-only-on-production-server and it hepled me.

Comment: Subhash, you haven't marked **any** answer on **any** of your questions as *accepted*. Continuing to fail to do so will lead to a situation where people will refuse to help you. You should really go through your question history and sort that out soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing this command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --class=RobbieP\CloudConvertLaravel\CloudConvertLaravelServiceProvider`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am getting the following error while running command  `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--class" option does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same issue for laravel V5.7.15, after revisiting the terminal I quickly found out that composer didn't install the cloudconvert package. I ran the following command to update `composer update`, cloudconvert package was installed. After installing  I ran the command again `php artisan vendor:publish`